# TypeError: 'Store' object is not iterable

Tags: python, flask

I want to search title with database record. Database record may contain sub-string in many cell which i want to search. I want to render all the records but could not shows because "TypeError: 'Store' object is not iterable" occurs.

My application.py is:

```
def bookresult():
    isbn = request.form.get("isbn")
    title = request.form.get("title")
    author = request.form.get("author")
    year = request.form.get("year")
    submit = []
    session = Session()
    result = session.query(Store).all()
    for result in result:
        if title in result.title:
            return render_template("bookresult.html",results=result)
    return render_template("login.html", message="Not found")
    session.commit()
```

And my bookresult.html is:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1> Search result book </h1>

    <table>

      <tr>
            <th> ISBN number </th>
            <th> Book title </th>
            <th> Author name </th>
            <th> Publish year </th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
{% for result in results %}
            <td> {{ result.isbn }} </td>
            <td> {{ result.title }} </td>
            <td> {{ result.author }} </td>
            <td> {{ result.year }} </td>
{% endfor %}
      </tr>

    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

Above code works if for loop in html file is removed. But how to get all the records without making iteration in html file.
How to get records iteratively in html file if my search string matched with database cell ?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error?

Comment: may be in html file..works if i remove for loop in html ..but it shows only one record if i remove for loop in html

Comment: 1. So, the problem is in the for-loop. Makes sense, it's where something is checked if it's an iterable; and 'result' apparently isn't.

Comment: 2. If you are asked, in a comment, to clarify your question - please understand that the clarification is needed in the question itself; so, don't answer in a comment, but edit your question to include that relevant information.

Comment: How to get result for all possible record..

Comment: @ItamarMushkin yes i had edited in question body

Comment: What's the output of 'result'?

Comment: it select all the records from table "store".

Comment: Add to your question a print of that variable. It's supposed to be an iterable, but apparently isn't right? So it makes sense to print out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Issue occurs in 
a) if .. is .. True syntax 
b) rendering in templates doesn't iterate over and over. You have to pass at once. 
c) {% for i in range(count) %} will cause iteration for int object i.e we can access elements of list as list[i] only.

Now application.py will look like:

```
@app.route("/bookresult", methods=['POST'])
def bookresult():
    isbn = request.form.get("isbn")
    title = request.form.get("title")
    author = request.form.get("author")
    year = request.form.get("year")
    session = Session()
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    list3 = []
    list4 = []
    results = session.query(Store).all()
#    return render_template("message.html",result=type(results))
    for i in results:
        if (title in i.title) is True:
            list1.append(i.isbn)
            list2.append(i.title)
            list3.append(i.author)
            list4.append(i.year)
#            counter = counter + 1
#        else:
#            counter = counter + 1
#        if (title in i) is True:
#            return render_template("bookresult.html",results=i)
#            counter = counter + 1
#        else:
#            counter = counter + 1
#    return render_template("bookresult.html", results=list1, list2, list3, list4)
    return render_template("bookresult.html", count=len(list1), result1=list1, result2=list2, result3= list3, result4= list4)
    session.commit()
```

And bookresult.html will be:

```
{% for i in range(count) %}
      <tr>

            <td> {{ result1[i] }} </td>
            <td> {{ result2[i] }} </td>
            <td> {{ result3[i] }} </td>
            <td> {{ result4[i] }} </td>

      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```